# xaml reference an element that includes its children

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, uwp

I have several pages that include the same border and its child elements.
Each page has

```
<Border Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource InstructionBox}" x:name="staticBorder">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Style="{StaticResource OnlyContentStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                Click="Instruction_Click">
            <Border >
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource InstructionStyle}">
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </Button>

        <Button Style="{StaticResource OnlyContentStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                Click="Logs_Click">
            <Border >
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource LogStyle}">
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </Button>
        <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="InstructionBorder">
            <StackPanel x:Name="PanelInstructions" Style="{StaticResource InstructionTextStyle}">
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Is there a way to make reference this border throughout all my pages?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean that you have the same border on multiple pages? Do you mean that you copied and pasted the <Border> element on to other pages?

Comment: Yes, I want to eliminate this method. I want to make a reference to an external source so that I only need to edit that one source instead of 10 pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no direct way. XAML only allows an element to exist in a single location on the [Visual Tree](https://wpftutorial.net/LogicalAndVisualTree.html). To do this you need to convert your border into a user control. There are several ways to do this. In the example below, I've used dependency properties to provide variable content for the first button in the user control's code behind. For the click event, I recommend binding the buttons Command to an ICommand implementation, but you need to be doing MVVM for that. This sample adds a RoutedEventHandler instead.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty InstructionButtonContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "InstructionButtonContent", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(InstructionBoxControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(FrameworkElement)));

public FrameworkElement InstructionButtonContent
{
    get { return (FrameworkElement) GetValue(InstructionButtonContentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(InstructionButtonContentProperty, value); }
}

public event RoutedEventHandler InstructionButtonClicked;

public InstructionBoxControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void InstructionButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    InstructionButtonClicked?.Invoke(sender, e);
}
```

For the most part you can paste the border into the user control's XAML. Then you need to bind the dynamic parts to the user control's DependencyProperties. You also hook up the button's click event call the RoutedEventHandler in the code behind above.

```
<Border >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Click="InstructionButtonClick">
            <Border>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=InstructionButtonContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:InstructionBoxControl}}}"/>
            </Border>
        </Button>
```

You can then use the new UserControl inplace of the border on any page like so:

```
<local:InstructionBoxControl InstructionButtonClicked="InstructionBoxControl_OnInstructionButtonClicked">
    <local:InstructionBoxControl.InstructionButtonContent>
        <TextBlock>Instructions</TextBlock>
    </local:InstructionBoxControl.InstructionButtonContent>
</local:InstructionBoxControl>
```

The other button and satckpanel should work similarly.

Comment: So what would the architecture look like for a single page application?

Comment: Do you have a single page app currently?

Comment: My comment is a bit out of scope. I will research more how to use user control. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Right. A UserControl helps with reusing XAML, but isn't going to really help with creating a SPA. The architecture for a SPA is an entirely different question.